# How to eliminate security concern while accessing to the file through program in R in Windows?

Tags: r, csv, security, data.table, stringi

While accessing to CSV file from disk with the help of the R program, where a path to the CSV file is provided in the configuration file ( A path is like *"testData/Amazon S3/Inventory/Accounts.csv"* which is provided in the Configuration file and **cfig[2]$save.location** is variable who is having value of this path accessed from Configuration file). Few lines of code are below

```
path <- cfig[2]$save.location
test_data <- fread(path,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,drop=col_ignor,blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
```

but it gave the message below:

> Taking input= as a system command ('testData/Amazon
>   S3/Inventory/Accounts.csv') and a variable has been used in the
>   expression passed to `input=`. Please use fread(cmd=...). There is a
>   security concern if you are creating an app and the app could have a
>   malicious user and the app is not running in a secure environment;
>   e.g. the app is running as root. Please read item 5 in the NEWS file
>   for v1.11.6 for more information and for the option to suppress this
>   message.
>   '*testData' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.* **Warning messages**:
>    1: In (if
>   (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") system else shell)(paste0("(",  :
>   '(testData/Amazon S3/Inventory/Accounts.csv) >
>   C:\Users\sharmb5\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOa25kH\filea78b5351f1'
>   execution failed with error code 1.
>    2: In fread(cfig[2]$save.location,
>   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, drop = col_ignor,  :   File
>   'C:\Users\sharmb5\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOa25kH\filea78b5351f1' has
>   size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.

when the following line of code executes,

`config[4]$save.location <- stri_replace_all(config[4]$save.location, cp_val, fixed = cp_key)`

It gives an error like as, `Error in [<-.data.table(*tmp*, j, value = list(TestCaseID = "C419760",  : Supplied 14 columns to be assigned 15 items. Please see NEWS for v1.12.2.`

The above error was a warning but after manually updating of packages. This warning turns into an error. What will be the reason behind this issue and how to solve it? Thanks for Advance!!!